# Quasar - how to change font (size, family) programmatically?

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I would like to create a "UI settings" page where user could set sm, md or lg font size, and pick a custom font for the quasar app.

Now, I know one can change colors to implement a similar task of UI themeing using:
https://quasar.dev/style/color-palette#util-setcssvar
but how can I achieve the same for the body font size, possibly also for space-base, typography-font-family etc.
In other words for variables listed here:
https://quasar.dev/style/sass-scss-variables#variables-list

I know I can override them statically (for the entire app, on build), but I would like to do that dynamically (and save it) so that **each user** can pick from several font families, font sizes etc.

I can do it via vanilla JS like this `document.body.style.setProperty('font-size', '32px');`  but I would like to tap into the quasar variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `quasar.variables.scss` file you can define

```scss
$body-font-size   : var(--q-theme-font-size, 20px);
$body-line-height : var(--q-theme-line-height, 1.2);
$typography-font-family: var(--q-theme-font-family, "'Roboto', '-apple-system', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif");
$button-font-size: var(--q-theme-btn-font-size, 16px);
```

Then you can use the above mentioned `setCssVar` helper function to set the desired CSS variables which will be picked up by the Quasar variables.

Comment: Well, that is the problem - it doesn't get picked up. setCssVar appears to work only for brand colors?
If I set $typography-font-family statically (in quasar.variableles.scss) it works,
However, in code:     setCssVar('$typography-font-family', 'Consolas'); does not get applied.

One more thing: it actually sets this variable (initally getCssVar returns null, and after I set it it returns Consolas) but it does not make a difference in the UI.
Is the VALUE of this var already "baked in" at the compile time into the CSS?

Comment: It does not get picked up because you are doing it wrong - `$typography-font-family` is the name of a **SASS** variable but `setCssVar` works with **CSS** variables. Therefore you should refer to `theme-font-size` like `setCssVar("theme-font-size", "20px");` Please note that the name of CSS variable has the format `--q-${name}` where **name** is what you use in `setCssVar` and `--q-xxxxx` is what you use with `var(....)` in the SASS/SCSS declarations.

Comment: You are right, thank you!